# How to change font size for code chunks in Quarto?

Tags: pdf, latex, r-markdown, quarto, beamer

I am using `quarto` to prepare a Beamer presentation. I would like to reduce the font size of the code inside a given chunk so everything fits better. See the example below:

[image]

The code that generates the chunk is:

````
```{python}
# Import packages
import numpy as np
```

```{python}
#| echo: true
w = np.array([0.7, 0.3])
Sigma = np.array([[0.09, 0.1], [0.1, 0.25]])

var_rp = w.T @ Sigma @ w
print("Variance of our example portfolio {:.4f}".format(var_rp))
print("Standard Deviation of our example portfolio {:.2f}".format(np.sqrt(var_rp)))
```
````

Is there a way to change the font size of this chunk so all lines of code fit in a single line in the pdf? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\AddToHookNext{env/Highlighting/begin}{\tiny}` to change the font size of the next chunk without affecting other chunks:

````
---
format: beamer
---

```{python}
# Import packages
import numpy as np
```

\AddToHookNext{env/Highlighting/begin}{\tiny}
```{python}
#| echo: true
w = np.array([0.7, 0.3])
Sigma = np.array([[0.09, 0.1], [0.1, 0.25]])

var_rp = w.T @ Sigma @ w
print("Variance of our example portfolio {:.4f}".format(var_rp))
print("Standard Deviation of our example portfolio {:.2f}".format(np.sqrt(var_rp)))
```
````

[image]

---

(in case you want to change the font size of all chunks, use `\AddToHook{env/Highlighting/begin}{\tiny}` in your header includes)

Answer (score 6):

Specify a `monofont` and scale down the font using `monofontoptions`. Check out the Quarto Beamer reference docs to know about these [font options](https://quarto.org/docs/reference/formats/presentations/beamer.html#fonts).

And I have used the font [`Source Code Pro`](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/sourcecodepro/) from the [LaTeX Font Catalogue](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/allfonts.html). You may look into there for other monospaced fonts.

````
---
title: "Small code font"
format: beamer
jupyter: python3
pdf-engine: lualatex
monofont: 'Source Code Pro'
monofontoptions: 
  - Scale=0.55
---

## Portfolio

Let's do this computation in python.....


```{python}
# Import packages
import numpy as np
```

```{python}
#| echo: true
w = np.array([0.7, 0.3])
Sigma = np.array([[0.09, 0.1], [0.1, 0.25]])

var_rp = w.T @ Sigma @ w
print("Variance of our example portfolio {:.4f}".format(var_rp))
print("Standard Deviation of our example portfolio {:.2f}".format(np.sqrt(var_rp)))
```
````

---

[image: code font size reduced]

---

*Note: This solution will reduce the font size for all code chunks and chunk output. If you want smaller font size for a specific code chunk, check the answer given by **samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz***.